# VBA Run-timer Error 1004 with .offSet()

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook containing properties, each with a respective property ID.
The code below aims to find the row corresponding to the ID chosen from a list in a comboBox and then fill the remainder of the fields in the form with the data in it's row.

```
Private Sub propertyCodeCombo_change()
    Set wks = Application.Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Property")
    Dim propertyCell As Range
    Set propertyCell = wks.Range("A2")
    Do Until propertyCell.Value = propertyCodeCombo.Value
        Set propertyCell = propertyCell.Offset(1, 0)   <--Error Occurs here
    Loop
    addressText = propertyCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    suburbText = propertyCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
    propertyTypeCombo = propertyCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
    bedroomsText = propertyCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
    bathroomsText = propertyCell.Offset(0, 5).Value
    weeklyRentalFeeText = propertyCell.Offset(0, 6).Value
    statusCombo = propertyCell.Offset(0, 7).Value
    commisionText = propertyCell.Offset(0, 8).Value
    ownerCodeCombo = propertyCell.Offset(0, 9).Value
End Sub
```

I find strange as I have almost identical code as seen below that does not cause an error and functions perfectly.

```
Set wks = Application.Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Property")
Dim propertyCell As Range
Set propertyCell = wks.Range("A2")
Do Until IsEmpty(propertyCell)
    Set propertyCell = propertyCell.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
```

Comment: Is the userform loaded?

Comment: @captainGrumpy Yeah the userForm is loaded

Comment: why not just `propertyCell.entireColumn.Find(propertyCodeCombo.Value,,xlWhole)`? If the find `is nothing` then just catch the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your code gets the error because you don't find a match, so your Offset command ends up reaching the last row of the sheet. Offsetting one more row will cause an error.

That's why your other *similar* code works - you apply a different test, so you exit the loop earlier.

You'll get much better performance with this code, as it uses an array instead of Offset:

```
Private Sub propertyCodeCombo_change()
  Dim wks As Worksheet

    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Property")
    Dim propertyCell As Range
    Set propertyCell = wks.Range("A2")

    Dim comboValue As Variant
    comboValue = propertyCodeCombo.Value

    Dim props As Variant
    props = wks.UsedRange.Value

    If IsArray(props) Then
    Dim propRow As Long
      For propRow = LBound(props) To UBound(props)

        If props(propRow, 1) = comboValue Then
          addressText = props(propRow, 2)
          suburbText = props(propRow, 3)
          propertyTypeCombo = props(propRow, 4)
          bedroomsText = props(propRow, 5)
          bathroomsText = props(propRow, 6)
          weeklyRentalFeeText = props(propRow, 7)
          statusCombo = props(propRow, 8)
          commisionText = props(propRow, 9)
          ownerCodeCombo = props(propRow, 10)
          Exit For
        End If
      Next propRow
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: An `application.match` returned to a variant may be appropriate. I find that the operation is usually completed before the time that sucking the `.UsedRange` into an array takes. Of course, there would also be the additional time of looking up all of the subsequent values.